# Making an automated watering system with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, c, code-review

I am trying to make an automated watering system using an Arduino.

Here is my wiring diagram:
[image: Wiring Diagram]
And here is my circuit wired up:
[image: Photo of wired circuit]

Here is the code that I'm using with Arduino. The code seems alright and the wiring on the Arduino seems okay as well, but I don't know where to place a speaker on the Arduino. The biggest problem is that the program doesn't run like I coded. After I uploaded this code to Arduino, the water pump just keeps running forever. Can anyone check up my code to make this run properly?

```
/**automated watering program **/

#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#define BEAT 300 // define time for the tone.
#define PINNO 12

int led = 13;

void setup() {
  // setup code to run once:
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // main code here, to run repeatedly:
  tone(PINNO,262,BEAT); // C(do)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,294,BEAT); // D(re)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,330,BEAT); // E(mi)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,262,BEAT); // C (do)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,294,BEAT); // D(re)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,330,BEAT); // E(mi)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,392,BEAT); // G(so)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,330,BEAT); // E(mi)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,294,BEAT); // D(re)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,262,BEAT); // C(do)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,294,BEAT); // D(re)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,330,BEAT); // E(mi)
  delay(BEAT);
  tone(PINNO,294,BEAT); // D(re)
  delay(BEAT);
  delay(1000); // Wait for 1 second
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH); //Make No. 11pin output HIGH = 5V
  delay(500); // Watering time
  digitalWrite(led,LOW); //Make No.11 pin output LOW = 0V
  // Shut down program to save battery using by watchdogtimer 24h standby mode
  int var = 0;
  while(var < 10800) {
    delayWDT(9); // 9seconds of shutdown
    var++; // 10800times repeat ＝24h
  }
}

void delayWDT(unsigned long t) {
  // delay excute while using powerdown mode
  delayWDT_setup(t); // watchdog timer setting
  ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN); // ADEN bit clear and stop ADC
  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); // Powerdow mode
  sleep_enable();
  sleep_mode(); // sleep mode
  sleep_disable(); // WatchDog Timer times up and start working again
  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN); // turn on the ADC
}

void delayWDT_setup(unsigned int ii) {
  // setting up timer
  // 0=16ms, 1=32ms, 2=64ms, 3=128ms, 4=250ms, 5=500ms
  // 6=1sec, 7=2sec, 8=4sec, 9=8sec
  byte bb;
  if (ii > 9 ) {
    // get rid of strange numbers
    ii = 9;
  }
  bb =ii & 7;
  if (ii > 7) {
    bb |= (1 << 5);
  }
  bb |= ( 1 << WDCE );
  MCUSR &= ~(1 << WDRF); // MCU Status Reg. Watchdog Reset  Flag ->0
  // start timed sequence
  WDTCSR |= (1 << WDCE) | (1<<WDE); // allow to edit watchdog
  // set new watchdog timeout value
  WDTCSR = bb;
  WDTCSR |= _BV(WDIE);
}
ISR(WDT_vect) {
  // the work after time up, WDT
  //  wdt_cycle++;
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you try controlling pin 11, where the pump is connected, and not pin 13, it may help. Also I can't understand your wiring there (but it looks wrong - there are components missing). Please provide a schematic (which you can do using the schematic editor available when you edit your question).

Comment: As for where to place a speaker - how about pin 12, like you have already decided in your code?

Comment: Thank you, I uploaded a diagram i wire them exactly like the diagram.

Comment: What model transistor is that?

Comment: it says BC5478, It came with Arduino Starter Kit.

Comment: also it was not speaker, it was Piezo. I don't know where to place it.

Comment: I'm missing a resistor between the arduino and the transistor. Also missing a (flyback) diode on the motor.

Answer (score 2):

Problems with your setup:

- Your pump is connected to pin 11 but you are controlling pin 13 (`int led = 13;`)
- You have an LED in line with your transistor base. That should be a resistor, and the LED should be in *parallel* with the base (with its own resistor).
- Your transistor is wired wrong. According to [the datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/410427.pdf) the pins are C-B-E as viewed from the angle in your wiring diagram. You have the Arduino connected to E instead of B, the pump connected to B instead of C, and ground connected to C instead of E.
- You don't have a flyback diode across the motor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXyfcE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why does it need the resistors ??

Comment: i tired this but didnt work

Comment: this time, speaker worked but the pump didnt work